# Decide, with justification, whether the subset consisting of eventually nil sequences is a subspace of $F^\infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $F^{\infty} = \{(x_n)_{n≥1} \mid x_n ∈ F\}$ denote the vector space over a field $F$, consisting of infinite sequences with entries in $F$. A sequence $(x_n)_{n≥1}$ is eventually nil if there is some positive integer $N$ so that $x_n = 0$ for all $n\geq N$.

Decide, with justification, whether the subset consisting of eventually nil sequences is a subspace of $F^∞$.

Let $U$ be the subset consisting of eventually nil sequences. To prove $U$ is a subspace, we need 3 things:

- 0 contained in $U$. So I think, if all $x_n=0$ then we have 0 which proves 0 is in $U$.
- If $u_1, u_2$ is in U, then $u_1+ u_2$ is in $U$
- If $a$ is in F, then $au$ is in $U$.

I have no idea how to prove the last 2 conditions. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do it all in one:

suppose $a,b \in F$, $X, Y \in U$.

$ax+ by \in F^{\infty}$ because $F^{\infty}$ is a vector space.

Also, $ax+by$ is eventually zero, as $x$ and $y$ are eventually zero. Explicitly, let $x_n = 0$  for  $n>N_1$,  $y_n = 0$ for $  n>N_2$. $ax+by = 0$ for $ n>\max(N_1,N_2)$. Hence $ax+by \in U$.

Hence $U$ is a vector subspace of $F^{\infty}$

Comment: Is there a reason why we should do it all in one? Because I'm used to separate it from class

Comment: no reason, it is just quicker

Comment: Okay thank you!